# Is There Any General XMLSchema that can be used to validate our XML string

Tags: c#

I want to compare my string To a XML Schema.

```
  string Parameetrs="<root><HostName>Arasanalu</HostName><AdminUserName>Administrator</AdminUserName><AdminPassword>1234</AdminPassword><PartitionNumber>2999</PartitionNumber><NanName nan=\"120901\"/><myparameter=\"ABC\"/></root>";
```

Is there any General XML Schema So that i can Validate My String to Check has valid XML format?

Note:String Parameters can take any number of arguments.

for validating do i need to Generate XSD from my string and comapre or we need to have general XML Schema?

Comment: Have a look [Validate XML Fragments Against an XML Schema in Visual C#.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318504)

Comment: Reading the string through an XML parser will tell you if the string is well-formed, that is, correct XML, with balanced tags and syntactically correct elements. To validate the string, you need a schema that matches the XML you provide. There is no "general XML schema" that will validate all XML strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the string will validate it.
The code below will throw an exception if the string is not valid xml.

```
  string Parameetrs = "<root><HostName></HostName></root>";
  var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
  xmlDoc.LoadXml(Parameetrs);
```

Comment: Thank you .Yes, But i want to compare with XML Schema then validate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try XmlDocument class LoadXml method.

see [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx)

This method will throw exception in case the string is not valid xml.

You can also use DTD defined in Xml like [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition)